# OpenGL ES2.0 - After restarting the App, everything looks.. weird

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

EDIT:

More debugging led me to the fact that glGetAttribLocation returns -1, except for the first start of the Application. Program ID is valid (I guess?), it was 12 in my testing right now. I also tried to retrieve attribute location right before drawing again, but this did not work out neither.

My shader "architecture" now looks like this:

I've turned the shader into a singleton. I.e. only one instance. Using it:

```
public void useProgram() {
    GLES20.glUseProgram(iProgram);
    getUniformLocations();
    getAttributeLocations();
}
```

I.e. program will be sent to OpenGL, afterwards I'm retrieving uniform and attribute locations for all my variables, they are stored within a HashMap (one for each shader):

```
@Override
protected void getAttributeLocations() {
    addToGLMap(A_NORMAL, GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(iProgram, A_NORMAL));
    addToGLMap(A_POSITION, GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(iProgram, A_POSITION));
    addToGLMap(A_COLOR, GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(iProgram, A_COLOR));
}
```

I don't understand, why the program's ID is for example 12, but all the attribute locations are non-existent in the second and the following run of my Application...

---

In my Application, I am loading a Wavefront object, as well as I am drawing several lines and cubes, just to try something. After starting the Application "clean", i.e. after rebooting or installing it, everything looks as intended. But if I close the Application and re-open it, it looks weird, screenshot is at the bottom.

What I'm currently doing:

onSurfaceCreated:

Taking care of culling, clear color, etc, etc.
Clear all loaded objects (just for testing, will of course not delete memory in later phase).
Reload objects (threaded).

My objects are stored like this:

```
public class WavefrontObject {
    private FloatBuffer mPositionBuffer = null;
    private FloatBuffer mColorBuffer = null;
    private FloatBuffer mNormalBuffer = null;
    private ShortBuffer mIndexBuffer = null;
}
```

- Buffers are filled upon creation of the element.

They are drawn:

```
mColorBuffer.position(0);
mNormalBuffer.position(0);
mIndexBuffer.position(0);
mPositionBuffer.position(0);


GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mShader.getGLLocation(BaseShader.A_POSITION), 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        0, mPositionBuffer);

GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mShader.getGLLocation(BaseShader.A_POSITION));

// etc...

GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, mIndexBuffer.capacity(), GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndexBuffer);
```

- Do I need to disable the VertexAttribArrays after drawing them? I am currently overwriting the buffer for each drawing loop, but do they maybe interact with other models being drawn?

The model I am loading displays a small toy-plane. After restarting the Application, it looks like this (loading the object, all colors are set to white (for testing)):

[image]

So to me it looks like the buffers either have left-over stuff in them? What's the "best practice" for using these buffers? Disable the arrays? Does OpenGL ES2.0 offer some sort of "clear buffer" method that I can use before putting my values in them?

What was expected to be drawn: At the point where the "weird triangles" and colors origin from, there should be the plane-model. All in white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your application loses context its OpenGL context is destroyed.
So all objects (programs and its uniform/attribute handles, etc) are invalidated.

During reopening you have to clear/invalidate all singleton objects like yours...